# Add css to embedded img tag

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to add some css to an embedded img tag that sits within a plugin called ngx-dropzone. I have a stackblitz example of my code. Basically I am trying to set the img to have a max width but can't seem to access the img tag properly.

This is the plugin component

```
  <ngx-dropzone-image-preview class="top-space" ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
  </ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
```

Once I upload an img it creates an img tag that I am trying to style.
[image]
Here is my stackblitz where you can upload an image and see it in action

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-g6cgmh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) as `None` as below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None         // here
})
```

Then define your css as,

```
 ngx-dropzone-image-preview > img {
      border: 10px solid red !important;
      min-width: 100px;
  }
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-image-encapsulation-none?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**

Comment: but use `viewEncapsulation` wisely.